# how to send file with other form data with put request using request module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, put, http-put

> Here is my code of put request

```
requestMethodPutWithFormData: function (url, form_data, header) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //SET ALL THESE PARATMETER TO MAKE REQUEST
        request.put({url: url, formData: form_data, headers: header}, function (error, response, body) {

                var responseData = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(responseData);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

> And my setting my form_data like this

```
var form_data = {
                        image_file: {
                            value: fs.createReadStream(files.file.path),
                            options: {
                                filename: files.file.name
                            }
                        },
                        store_id: fields.store_id,
                        image_file_id: fields.image_file_id,
                        token_type: g_token_type,
                        account_id: g_account_id
                    };
```

My problem is the data of formData is not receiving on the requested URL it is showing data null, but can not understand the point that this code is absolutely working fine with post request but not with put request data is not receiving at the endpoint.

> Please help me to overcome this problem